# html curly quotation marks breaking script

Tags: html, quote

I found this script online for a dropdown multi level navbar which I have been adapting. It has now come time to sort all my links out. However when I try to add my links, I noticed the use of open and close quote marks. When I try and replace them with the default stright one, my css dissapears from the link. 
This isn't something I have ever come across before. And I have tried searching but all I come back with is a lot of info on curly vs straight quotation marks.

```
    <body>
<div class="container" style="width: 80%; height: 163px">
<div class="bubble" style="left: 6px; top: -31px; width: 1013px; height: 800px; background-image: url('../../images/FreeVector-Striped-Waves1%20copy-1%20(Copy).jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat"> 
<div class="content">
<div class ="nav_image">
    <img src="../../navbar/backbar.gif" height="114"/><br />
            <nav>
                    <ul style="left: 243px; top: -2px; width: 658px; height: 0px">
                    <li class='active'><a href=”../../homepage.htm“>Home</a></li>
                    <li class='has-sub'><a href=”#“>Cottages</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="has-sub"><a href="cottages/farmhouse/farmhouse.htm">Farmhouse</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/cottages/farmhouse/facilities.htm">Facilities</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/cottages/farmhouse/guestbook.htm">Guest Book</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/cottages/farmhouse/booking rates.htm">Booking Rates</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="has-sub"><a href="cottages/granary/granary.htm">Granary</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="cottages/granary/facilities.htm">Facilities</a></li>
                            <li><a href="cottages/granary/guest book.htm">Guest Book</a></li>
                            <li><a href="cottages/granary/booking rates.htm">Booking Rates</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="has-sub"><a href="cottages/the barn/the barn.htm">The Barn</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="cottages/the barn/facilities.htm">Facilities</a></li>
                            <li><a href="cottages/the barn/guest book.htm">Guest Book</a></li>
                            <li><a href="cottages/the barn/guest book.htm">Booking Rates</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>

<li><a href=”../croyde.htm“>Croyde</a></li>
<li><a href=”../contactus.htm“>Contact us</a></li>

</ul>

</nav>
```

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct the `”` to `"`.
Copy and paste from Word document?

Comment: H, thanks for the response. I found out the problem today and it was an issue with the curly quote blocking some css. Its all sorted now. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `”` or `“` . Just use normal quotes `"` or `'`